# Solution for "Diffusion-Like" 1-D Navier-Stokes Equation With Moving Boundaries

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Consider an incompressible fluid, with viscosity $\mu$ and density $\rho$,
flowing vertically in an annulus, described in cylindrical coordinates
$$\left\{ r,\theta,z\right\}, \; \text{with } r=a, r=b, \text{ and } b>a$$ at the
boundaries and the boundary walls moving in a time-dependent fashion.

Simplifying the Navier-Stokes Equation where fluid velocity $\vec{u}=u_{z}(r,t)$
gives a one-dimensional form similar to the diffusion equation:

$$\frac{\partial u_{z}}{\partial t}=\frac{\mu}{\rho}\left[\frac{1}{r}\frac{\delta u_{z}}{\delta r}+\frac{\partial^{2}u_{z}}{\delta r^{2}}\right],$$

with boundary conditions where $U,\omega$ are constants:

$$u_{z}(a,t)=Ua\sin(\omega t), u_{z}(b,t)=Ub\sin(\omega t), \text{and }u_{z}(r,0)=0.$$

Can this be solved by Separation of Variables? Could the solution
for $u_{z}$ give a sigmoidal relation between z and t for $0\leq\omega t\leq\pi$

Many thanks,

Tiernan

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. I edited the question to make it easier to be looked at. Also I removed the ([tag:differential-equations]) tag, which is supposed to be for ODE.

Comment: @Shuhao Cao Thanks for the welcome and improving the format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u_z(r,t)=v_z(r,t)+Ur\sin\omega t$ ,

Then $\dfrac{\partial u_z(r,t)}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial v_z(r,t)}{\partial t}+U\omega r\cos\omega t$

$\dfrac{\partial u_z(r,t)}{\partial r}=\dfrac{\partial v_z(r,t)}{\partial r}+U\sin\omega t$

$\dfrac{\partial^2u_z(r,t)}{\partial r^2}=\dfrac{\partial^2v_z(r,t)}{\partial r^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{\partial v_z(r,t)}{\partial t}+U\omega r\cos\omega t=\dfrac{\mu}{\rho}\left(\dfrac{1}{r}\left(\dfrac{\partial v_z(r,t)}{\partial r}+U\sin\omega t\right)+\dfrac{\partial^2v_z(r,t)}{\partial r^2}\right)$

$\dfrac{\partial v_z(r,t)}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\mu}{\rho}\left(\dfrac{\partial^2v_z(r,t)}{\partial r^2}+\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial v_z(r,t)}{\partial r}\right)+\dfrac{U\mu\sin\omega t}{\rho r}-U\omega r\cos\omega t$

with $v_z(a,t)=0$ and $v_z(b,t)=0$

Comment: @doraeamonpaul Many thanks for your answer. The pde is now in a form that I can attempt to solve by Separation of Variables for a inhomogeneous diffusion equation